What is the proper way of saving user extra details after Apple Login with Flutter?
I seem to be having massive issues with Apple login on Flutter whereas the Google login works completely smoothly with login/relogin/save full name etc
I dont believe i have the check correct on wether its their forst time logging in or not. Difference with Apple being they only give the name and email on the first login.
This is my latest attempt but im not sure if im doing it correct. Does anyone have a working example of saving details and logging back in that they are happy with?
Future<User?> signInWithApple() async {
try {
  final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: [
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName
    ],
  );

  final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
    idToken: credential.identityToken,
    accessToken: credential.authorizationCode,
  );

  final userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
  final user = userCredential.user;

  if (user == null) {
    throw const Failure(
        code: 'user-credential-null',
        message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.');
  }

  await user.updateDisplayName(
      "${credential.familyName} ${credential.givenName}");

  if (user.displayName != null) {
    await saveAppleDetails()
  } 


  return user;
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
  throw Failure(
      code: err.code,
      message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.');
} on SignInWithAppleAuthorizationException catch (err) {
  switch (err.code) {
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.canceled:
      return null;
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.failed:
      throw Failure(
          code: 'apple-sign-in-error',
          message: 'Apple Sign-In error: ${err.message}');
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.invalidResponse:
      throw Failure(
          code: 'apple-sign-in-error',
          message: 'Apple Sign-In error: ${err.message}');
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.notHandled:
      throw Failure(
          code: 'apple-sign-in-error',
          message: 'Apple Sign-In error: ${err.message}');
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.notInteractive:
      throw Failure(
          code: 'apple-sign-in-error',
          message: 'Apple Sign-In error: ${err.message}');
    case AuthorizationErrorCode.unknown:
      throw Failure(
          code: 'apple-sign-in-error',
          message: 'Apple Sign-In error: ${err.message}');
  }
} catch (err) {
  throw const Failure(
      code: '', message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.');
}

}
